# Proof completenes of $ \{x \in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}\ |\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n |x_n|^p < \infty \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n$: $0 < s_n \leq \frac{1}{n} $. Let $p>1$.

How to show that the space of sequences

$ l^p_s := \{x \in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}\ |\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n |x_n|^p < \infty \}  $ is complete in respect to the norm $ ||x||:= (\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n |x_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p} }$.

I tried to fix a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and show that $(x_n(k))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy Sequence, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact  that $\ell^{p}(\mathbb C ^{\mathbb N})$ is complete and the map $(x_n) \to (s_n^{1/p}x_n)$  is an isometric isomorphism. The condition $s_n \leq \frac  1 n$ plays no role in this. Alternatively, you can imitate the proof of completeness of $\ell^{p}(\mathbb C ^{\mathbb N})$.

Comment: The imitation of the completeness of $l^p$ yields the result. But eventhough the idea of using an isometry is interesting, this ismorphism actually is not a bijection. Hence this approach does not work. Thank you :)

Comment: @Slyder It is a bijection. If $(y_n) \in \ell_s^{p}$ then  $(x_n) =(s_n^{-1/p}y_n) \in \ell^{p}$ and $(y_n)$ is the image of $(x_n)$. Of course, the map is also one-to-one.